# Record the purchase of a publication

Tags: civicontribute

I am working with an organisation that wants to record the purchase of publications that they sell.  What is the best way of doing this?

The publications are purchased through a variety of channels including in cash and via third party websites such as Amazon.  The purchase itself would not be processed via CiviCRM but they would like to be able to record the purchases within CiviCRM so that they can report on sales figures.

In terms of reporting they would like to know how many publications have been sold each month and how much income each type of publication has generated.

Would it be best to record these purchases using CiviContribute or as a custom activity type.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go down the CiviContribute approach first with a PriceSet and a specific 'contribution type'